# Is there a way to find the mean length of words in a string in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am new to R and Webscraping. As practice I am trying to scrape information from a fake book website. I have managed to scrape the book titles, but I now want find the mean word length for each individual word in the book titles. For example, if there were two books 'book example' 'random books' the mean word length would be 22/4 = 5.5. I am currently able to find out the mean length of the full book titles, but I need to split them all into individual words, and then find the mean length.

Code:

```
url<-'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('h3 a') %>%
  html_attr('title')->titles
titles

values<-lapply(titles,nchar)
mean(unlist(values))
```

Output:

```
 [1] "A Light in the Attic"                                                                          
 [2] "Tipping the Velvet"                                                                            
 [3] "Soumission"                                                                                    
 [4] "Sharp Objects"                                                                                 
 [5] "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind"                                                         
 [6] "The Requiem Red"                                                                               
 [7] "The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job"                                            
 [8] "The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull"       
 [9] "The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics"
[10] "The Black Maria"                                                                               
[11] "Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade Trilogy, #1)"                                                
[12] "Shakespeare's Sonnets"                                                                         
[13] "Set Me Free"                                                                                   
[14] "Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)"                                       
[15] "Rip it Up and Start Again"                                                                     
[16] "Our Band Could Be Your Life: Scenes from the American Indie Underground, 1981-1991"            
[17] "Olio"                                                                                          
[18] "Mesaerion: The Best Science Fiction Stories 1800-1849"                                         
[19] "Libertarianism for Beginners"                                                                  
[20] "It's Only the Himalayas" 

[1] 35.35 # Current mean value (of full book title, but I want average word length)
```

Is there a way to focus on each word and find the mean length of all individual words in the book titles? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the `titles` into words and count the mean number of characters in each word.

```
mean(nchar(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+'))))
#[1] 5.161017
```

Note that since we are splitting on whitespace this has words like `"1981-1991"`, `"(Scott"`, `"#1)"` etc. which should be ok for larger samples. If you don't want to include them you may need to clarify the requirement of what constitutes a word.

Comment: Splitting on non word characters with `\\W` Is another option depending on the requirements.